# Question about 3/~5 output select pin of a boost IC?

Tags: arduino, switch-mode-power-supply, boost, switching-regulator, nrf24l01

I want to power up Arduino nano and nRF24l01+ 's Vcc from MAX756 step-up DC-DC convertor ([datasheet](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/arpdf/MAX756-MAX757.pdf)). I'm using a single AA battery (1.5V)

There is a 3/5(bar) pin to select whether the output would be 3.3 or 5V.
The pin recognizes max 0.4V as low and min 1.6V as high.
[image: MAX756 3/~5 pin]
Now If I connect that pin to ground, it would produce 5V but what should the pin voltage be if I want 3.3V?

**1-** How can I select 3.3V OUT if I'm only using 1.5V battery in the input? Should the pin be connected to OUT if I want 3.3V?
**2-** If so, how does the IC even work? It first wants to know what voltage to produce in OUT therefore it checks 3/~5 pin. But if it is connected to OUT, wouldn't this situation be a paradox?
**3-** nRF24l01+ is very sensitive in it's VCC. It should never be 5V. Would connecting OUT to 3/~5 pin, create a transient 5V in OUT and burn the RF module?
**4-** What is meant by this line (bootstrapped?) is the datasheet?

> The device is internally bootstrapped, with power derived from the
> output voltage (via OUT).

Thank you very much

Comment: You are allowed to connect this pin to the output, via a resistor. The device itself gains its main power from its own output, too. An internal bootstrap circuit helps starting from the input as long the output doesn't supply power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extract of the table in your question describes two pins. One is the shutdown pin and the other is the output voltage select pin (pin 2). Read the data sheet and look at the pin out and all will become clear. Connect pin 2 to the output to select 3.3 volts.

It seems that you should use a 1 Mohm resistor in series with the pin when connecting to the output.

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator Are you unhappy with this answer? Do you have any questions?